# Wcf how to verify the caller identity?

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a vb project and a WCF service. When I install the project on a different computer every time, how can I verify the identity of each caller without login and I research in microsoft website

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/service-identity-and-authentication

and I try to set SSL to verity but this way doesn't seem to be getting caller's identity

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication

It any way to get caller identity without login and sample code to refer?

Comment: What exactly does "identity" mean in this context?

Comment: In my project have many user, I want to know who called the wcf, I thought about using IP but IP will be change.

Comment: So you want something to identify a user.  That's what a user name is for.  Without passwords though, you can't stop people using the user name of a different user.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question on SO, I think you should reconsider this. You can't prevent clients from calling your service with the same username and password. So what is your client identity? You can use transport layer security and use certificates as credentials to determine the identity of the caller.
Please refer to the following link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/authentication-in-wcf